# Generating ssl certificate in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl-certificate

I have crt and key files. I don't find how to implement the self signed certificate in the asp.net application code.

Chatgpt suggested this:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var certPath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/localhost.crt");
            var keyPath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/localhost.key");
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateSelectionCallback += (sender, hostname, clientCertificates, serverCertificate, certificateAuthorities) =>
            {
                var cert = new X509Certificate2(certPath);
                return cert;
            };
        }


public class TrustAllCertificatesPolicy : System.Net.ICertificatePolicy
    {
        private string certificatePath;
        private string privateKeyPath;

        public TrustAllCertificatesPolicy(string certPath, string keyPath)
        {
            certificatePath = certPath;
            privateKeyPath = keyPath;
        }

        public bool CheckValidationResult(System.Net.ServicePoint srvPoint, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certificate, System.Net.WebRequest request, int certificateProblem)
        {
            // Load the certificate and private key from the provided paths
            var cert = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(certificatePath);
            var privateKey = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(privateKeyPath);

            // Assign the certificate and private key to the request
            var requestWithCertificate = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)request;
            requestWithCertificate.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
            requestWithCertificate.PrivateKey = new System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider();
            requestWithCertificate.PrivateKey.FromXmlString(privateKey);

            return true;
        }
    }
```

but it is giving me errors:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State

1. Error    CS0136  A local or parameter named 'sender' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter
2. Error    CS0117  'ServicePointManager' does not contain a definition for 'ServerCertificateSelectionCallback'
3. Error    CS1061  'HttpWebRequest' does not contain a definition for 'PrivateKey' and no accessible extension method 'PrivateKey' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpWebRequest' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: "it is giving me errors" - what errors? Please [edit] the question and include them.

Comment: "I don't find how to implement the self signed certificate" implement *what? What do you want to do with a self-signed certificate?

Comment: I want that the website will know the certificate. I created the cert through openssl and I can't understand how to connect it to a server.